# What nodes will the data written into the default database of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I have already created an Apache IoTDB database on server. I want to know if I directly write data into IoTDB without creating another database, will the data automatically be written into the first two nodes created in the default database? Any settings that I need to know before I start writing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the configuration of Apache IoTDB is set by default or the automatically creating metadata function is open, then yes, the data will be written into the first two nodes automatically.
If your data writing is in such path: `insert into root.db.device(time,s1,s2) values (...)`, then the automatically created database in IoTDB is `root.db`.